# Cross device testing of sencha touch application using seista

Tags: sencha-touch-2, cross-platform, siesta

Does siesta testing framework support cross device testing? Do we have any documentation around it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Siesta test suites can be run on any device. You just open a web page on the target device and pointing it to your harness file. Right now though we do not support automation for mobile devices, you can always run your tests in Chrome though.